# Web indexing and duplicate content about multiple url for one website

Tags: indexing, web

I have one website and several url :

- http://aaa.com
- http://bbb.com
- ...
- http://nnn.com

All of these links go to the same website. The website have a global skeleton like this :

```
<body>
  <p>name : <?php echo $var1; ?> </p>
  <p>surname : <?php echo $var2; ?> </p>
  <p>age : <?php echo $var3; ?> </p> 
</body>
```

My question is about the web indexing. The skeleton still the same whatever the url used. But ! the skeleton have some variables, these variables change depending the base url used.

So, my website will detected as a 'duplicate content' or not for searches bots ?

Thank you =)

Comment: So it is like this: when the user types `http://aaa.com` they will see the age of lets say 10, when the user has a url like `http://bbb.com` they will see a age like 20? Is that how you ment the question?

Comment: Or is your question about how the e.g. Google will detect the website, if the website with the url of `http://aaa.com` is the same as `http://bbb.com`?

Comment: @Arendax : yes for first question :) if go to aaa.com (age 10) and go to bbb.com (age 20) will detected by google as a duplicate content (the html skeleton still the same but variables in the skeleton change)

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to know: **1)** Thinks e.g. Google that your page is a duplicate?, or **2)** How to make it that on a url your page displays other value's?

Comment: sorry for my unclears asks , its the 1 !

Comment: Any interests in accepting my answer as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, Google will think your web-pages are the same if you only have a couple of rows of text that are different. Google will display only one of the websites in the search results.

> Google tries hard to index and show pages with distinct information. This filtering means, for instance, that if your site has a "regular" and "printer" version of each article, and neither of these is blocked with a noindex meta tag, we'll choose one of them to list.
>
> In the rare cases in which Google perceives that duplicate content may be shown with intent to manipulate our rankings and deceive our users, we'll also make appropriate adjustments in the indexing and ranking of the sites involved.
>
> As a result, the ranking of the site may suffer, or the site might be removed entirely from the Google index, in which case it will **no longer** appear in search results. [More info.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en)